Error al intentar actulizar campos de una tabla
En esta parte del código está dentro de un while, de la tabla hay columnas las cuales solo estas 4 de hora y fecha se subiran cuando el usuario escoga las opciones, cuando ponga la opción de "Working on it" debe de actualizar la tabla, pero no lo hace. No me manda error con el alert al eleguir una de de las opciones.
La idea de esto es que sea un tipo task manger
echo "<td><select class='status' data-id='" . $row["id"] . "' onchange='handleStatusChange()'>
        <option value='Done' " . ($row["status"] == "Done" ? "selected" : "") . ">Done</option>
        <option value='Working on it' " . ($row["status"] == "Working on it" ? "selected" : "") . ">Working on it</option>
        <option value='Stuck' " . ($row["status"] == "Stuck" ? "selected" : "") . ">Stuck</option>
        <option value='Not Started' " . ($row["status"] == "Not Started" ? "selected" : "") . ">Not Started</option>
        </select></td>";

Esta es la función de JS, en la consola me manda error en la linea 3.
function handleStatusChange() {
        const select = document.getElementById('data-id');
        const value = select.value;
        const id = this.getAttribute('data-id');  // Asegúrate de obtener el 'id'

        let action;
        if (value === 'Working on it') {
            action = 'start';
        } else if (value === 'Done') {
            action = 'finish';
        }
        if (action) {
            updateTask(id, action);
        }
    };

   function updateTask(id, action) {
  var formData = new FormData();  // Define correctamente formData aquí
  formData.append('id', id);      // Asegúrate de añadir 'id' al FormData
  formData.append('action', action);  // Añade la 'acción' al FormData

fetch('update_task_dates.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
})
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    return response.json();  // Asegúrate de procesar la respuesta como JSON
})
.then(data => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
    alert(data.message || 'Action completed successfully');
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    alert('Error processing your request: ' + error.message);
});
}

El php para actualizar los campos de la base datos dependiendo de si es start o finish.
<?php
  include 'conn.php';  

 header('Content-Type: application/json');
      if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['action'])) {
  $action = $_POST['action'];

   if ($action == 'start') {
    
    $sql = "UPDATE dibujo SET (fecha_inicio_status, hora_inicio_status) VALUES 
   (CURDATE(), CURTIME())";
} elseif ($action == 'finish') {
  
    $sql = "UPDATE dibujo SET (fecha_final_status, hora_final_status) VALUES 
(CURDATE(), CURTIME())";
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
        echo json_encode(["message" => "Record inserted successfully"]);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(["error" => "No record inserted. Check your query"]);
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo json_encode(["error" => "Error preparing statement: " . $conn->error]);
}
$conn->close();
} else {
echo json_encode(["error" => "Invalid request"]);
}

?>


Estos son los campos que deben de ponerse al escoger cada opción
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value') at handleStatusChange (script.js:3:34) at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (index.php:138:98)
Este error me da al usar el select, la parte de index.php es el codigo del select y el de scripy.js es la funcion handleStatusChange().

en la consola me manda error en la linea 3.... que error?? cual es la linea 3??

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
at handleStatusChange (script.js:3:34)
at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (index.php:138:98), ese error me da en el JS y el index es en donde esta el select

Diria que confundes esto:  document.getElementById('data-id') pues el data-id no es un id sino mas bien un atributo.  Intenta cambiar la función para que le puedas pasar el parametro del id, es decir, que sea algo asi como onchange='handleStatusChange(row[id]) y lo recoges en el javascript (corrigiendo los errores de formato que pongo, claro),  y claro, pon el id=row[id] correspondiente.

Los errores como texto en la pregunta por favor.. usa el boton [edit] y agrega todo lo que falte... ademas, cual seria ese archivo??
